# Storing JSON data in Aerospike in Python

Tags: python, json, aerospike, nosql

I'm trying to retrieve response from ip-api.com for most IP ranges. But I want to store that data in Aerospike but I'm having some errors.

Here is the Python script

```
# import the module
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
import urllib2
config = {
  'hosts': [ ('127.0.0.1', 3000) ]
}

try:
  client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
except:
  import sys
  print("failed to connect to the cluster with", config['hosts'])
  sys.exit(1)

key = ('ip', 'hit', 'trial')

try:
  for i in range(0,255):
    for j in range(0,255):
        for k in range(0,255):
            for l in range(0,255):
                if not((i == 198 and j == 168) or (i == 172 and j > 15 and j < 32) or (i == 10)):
                    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ip-api.com/json/'+str(i)+'.'+str(j)+'.'+str(k)+'.'+str(l))
                    html = response.read()
                    client.put(key, html)
except Exception as e:
  import sys
  print("error: {0}".format(e), file=sys.stderr)


client.close()
```

I'm new to Python as well as Aerospike, infact any no-SQL databases. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to get an idea what that object in _html_ looks like, and what erros you're seeing. The [aerospike.Client.put](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.put) method is pretty simple - it expects key-value pairs.

Comment: Please use proper capitalization!

Answer (score 1):

All code from aerospike perspective it right, except you would want to change

```
html = response.read()
client.put(key, html)
```

to

```
import json

client.put(key, json.load(response))
```

The response is a json string which needs to be converted to json object

Comment: This is what comes up after using your solution **error: No JSON object could be decoded**

Comment: That is because the response for that particular query is not a valid json. Try curl on that url or through the browser.